# how to display two details of tables from a correlated subquery. #mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I want to display details of package along with the details of its least expensive subactivities.
Suppose there is A01,A02,A03
A01 is the package and A03 is the least expensive childactivity,
So my select statement should display details of A01,A03

However I do not understand how can I display the details of the least expensive sub-activity[A03] along with A01.

I know I have to use correlated subquery but still can't get it to work.

Right now it only displays result of package with least expensive.

DDLs

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Activity` (
  `ActivityID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `ActivityName` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `ActivityCost` float(2) NULL,
  `ActivityType` VARCHAR(45) NULL);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Package` (
  `PackageActivityID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `ChildActivityID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_Package_Activity1_idx` (`PackageActivityID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_Package_Activity2_idx` (`ChildActivityID` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Package_Activity1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`PackageActivityID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Activity` (`ActivityID`)
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Package_Activity2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ChildActivityID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`Activity` (`ActivityID`);

insert into activity values ('A01', 'Kayaking', 120, 'B');
insert into activity values ('B01', 'Seaking', 420, 'I');
insert into activity values ('C01', 'maya', 220, 'O');
insert into activity values ('D01', 'bing', 170, 'B');

insert into package (packageactivityid, childactivityid) values ('A01','C01');
insert into package (packageactivityid, childactivityid) values ('F01','F01');
insert into package (packageactivityid, childactivityid) values ('D01','D01');
insert into package (packageactivityid, childactivityid) values ('E01','E01');
insert into package (packageactivityid, childactivityid) values ('B01','B01');
```

To recap, I'm hoping to achieve this result:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| PackageActivityID | ChildActivityID | ActivityID | ActivityName | ActivityCost | ActivityType |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| A01               | C01             | A01        | Kayaking     |          120 | B            |
| A01               | C01             | A01        | Kayaking     |          120 | B            |
| A01               | C01             | A01        | Kayaking     |          120 | B            |
| A01               | C01             | A01        | Kayaking     |          120 | B            |
| D01               | D01             | D01        | bing         |          170 | B            |
| D01               | D01             | D01        | bing         |          170 | B            |
| D01               | D01             | D01        | bing         |          170 | B            |
| D01               | D01             | D01        | bing         |          170 | B            |
| B01               | B01             | B01        | Seaking      |          420 | I            |
| B01               | B01             | B01        | Seaking      |          420 | I            |
| B01               | B01             | B01        | Seaking      |          420 | I            |
| B01               | B01             | B01        | Seaking      |          420 | I            |
+-------------------+-----------------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

My attempted query:

```
select activityid, activityname, activitycost 
from package p, activity a
where p.PackageActivityID = a.ActivityID
and p.ChildActivityID = (select ActivityID
from package p,activity a
where a.activityid = p.ChildActivityID
having min(activitycost));
```

My query only displays the packageactivity details but not the details of childactivity.

Comment: Add `activity` table definition. Remove all keys/constraints from DDLs.

Comment: `having min(activitycost)` simply checks does `min(activitycost)` is not a zero (or empty string or NULL).

Comment: Note that there are very few problems that you require you to 'have to do' a particular thing. A correlated subquery is just a choice, and sometimes it's the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am following correctly, you can use window functions:

```
select p.*, a.*
from package p
inner join (
    select a.*, rank() over(partition by activityid order by activitycost) rn
    from activity a
) a on p.PackageActivityID = a.activityid
where a.rn = 1
```

Basically, this brings the less details of the less expensive activity for each package - which is how I understand your question. Ties are allowed here.

In MySQL < 8.0, where window functions are not available, an alternative uses a correlated subquery for filtering:

```
select p.*, a.*
from package p
inner join activity a  on p.PackageActivityID = a.activityid
where a.activitycost = (
    select min(a1.activitycost)
    from activity a1
    where a1.activityid = a.activityid
)
```

Comment: this solved it. I will accept after the time limit is passed.